# Thymeleaf vs Angular

Tags: java, spring

Minhas buscam dizem que o Thymeleaf é um template engine que renderiza no server, enquanto o Angular seria um framework front end, que renderiza no client. Pergunto.

1 - Minhas busca esta correta, vocês adicionariam algo nessa explicação?

2 - É possível usar os dois juntos no Spring MVC? Se sim, faz sentindo? Por exemplo?

3 - Poderia se dizer que o "Thymeleaf seria um JSF da vida"?

Answer (score 0):

É possível, o angular é usado para desenvolvimento api-rest no spring, thymeleaf usa-se para server render, angular é cliente render, sendo assim é possível usar os dois, cada caso é um caso sendo que um anota-se com @RestController e outro com @Controller.